# Elastic Search failed to start - invalid SSL configuration for xpack.security.transport.ssl

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl

The OS version is CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core), I tried two rpms for installation and none worked properly: elasticsearch-1.7.3.noarch.rpm and elasticsearch-8.4.2-x86_64.rpm. For the latter, When running `sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service` it cannot finish booting Elasticsearch, and the log shows "invalid SSL configuration for xpack.security.transport.ssl".

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73127698/elasticsearchsecurityexception-invalid-configuration-for-xpack-security-transpo) and [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/invalid-configuration-for-xpack-security-transport-ssl/297989) and cannot find the answer and need more help.

I don't know any (initial) password, the installation process did not prompt me any information.

Infor_1:

```
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]# pwd
/etc/elasticsearch
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]# ls -tl
total 64
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch  2969 Sep 27 10:48 elasticsearch.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch  2635 Sep 27 10:23 jvm.options
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch  2637 Sep 26 17:55 jvm.options.rpmsave
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch  4303 Sep 26 17:53 elasticsearch.yml.rpmsave
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch   536 Sep 26 16:58 elasticsearch.keystore
drwxr-x--- 2 root elasticsearch  4096 Sep 26 16:58 certs
drwxr-s--- 2 root elasticsearch  4096 Sep 15 00:33 jvm.options.d
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch  1042 Sep 15 00:29 elasticsearch-plugins.example.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch 17417 Sep 15 00:29 log4j2.properties
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch   473 Sep 15 00:29 role_mapping.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch   197 Sep 15 00:29 roles.yml
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch     0 Sep 15 00:29 users
-rw-rw---- 1 root elasticsearch     0 Sep 15 00:29 users_roles
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch --version
Version: 8.4.2, Build: rpm/89f8c6d8429db93b816403ee75e5c270b43a940a/2022-09-14T16:26:04.382547801Z, JVM: 18.0.2.1
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]# /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-keystore list
autoconfiguration.password_hash
keystore.seed
xpack.security.http.ssl.keystore.secure_password
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.secure_password
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.secure_password
```

Config_1 (elasticsearch.yml):

```
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]# cat elasticsearch.yml
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
network.host: 127.0.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Readiness ----------------------------------
#
# Enable an unauthenticated TCP readiness endpoint on localhost
#
#readiness.port: 9399
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false
xpack.security.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
```

Config_2 (jvm.options):

```
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]# cat jvm.options
################################################################
##
## JVM configuration
##
################################################################
##
## WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. If you want to override the
## JVM options in this file, or set any additional options, you
## should create one or more files in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing your adjustments.
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/jvm-options.html
## for more information.
##
################################################################



################################################################
## IMPORTANT: JVM heap size
################################################################
##
## The heap size is automatically configured by Elasticsearch
## based on the available memory in your system and the roles
## each node is configured to fulfill. If specifying heap is
## required, it should be done through a file in jvm.options.d,
## which should be named with .options suffix, and the min and
## max should be set to the same value. For example, to set the
## heap to 4 GB, create a new file in the jvm.options.d
## directory containing these lines:
##
## -Xms4g
## -Xmx4g
-Xms256m
-Xmx256m
##
## See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/heap-size.html
## for more information
##
################################################################


################################################################
## Expert settings
################################################################
##
## All settings below here are considered expert settings. Do
## not adjust them unless you understand what you are doing. Do
## not edit them in this file; instead, create a new file in the
## jvm.options.d directory containing your adjustments.
##
################################################################

-XX:+UseG1GC

## JVM temporary directory
-Djava.io.tmpdir=${ES_TMPDIR}

## heap dumps

# generate a heap dump when an allocation from the Java heap fails; heap dumps
# are created in the working directory of the JVM unless an alternative path is
# specified
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

# exit right after heap dump on out of memory error
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

# specify an alternative path for heap dumps; ensure the directory exists and
# has sufficient space
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch

# specify an alternative path for JVM fatal error logs
-XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log

## GC logging
-Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m
[root@ali01 elasticsearch]#
```

log (`tail -f /var/log/elasticsearch/my-application.log`):

```
[2022-09-27T10:49:34,001][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] version[8.4.2], pid[14086], build[rpm/89f8c6d8429db93b816403ee75e5c270b43a940a/2022-09-14T16:26:04.382547801Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/18.0.2.1/18.0.2.1+1-1]
[2022-09-27T10:49:34,037][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] JVM home [/usr/share/elasticsearch/jdk], using bundled JDK [true]
[2022-09-27T10:49:34,037][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] JVM arguments [-Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -Xms256m, -Xmx256m, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-10477436689482229078, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/elasticsearch, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/elasticsearch/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=/var/log/elasticsearch/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=134217728, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.distribution.type=rpm, --module-path=/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib, --add-modules=jdk.net, -Djdk.module.main=org.elasticsearch.server]
[2022-09-27T10:49:39,206][INFO ][c.a.c.i.j.JacksonVersion ] [node-1] Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.13.2, jackson-core=2.13.2, jackson-databind=2.13.2.2, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.13.2, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.13.2, azure-core=1.27.0, Troubleshooting version conflicts: https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,620][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,620][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,621][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [constant-keyword]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,621][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [data-streams]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,621][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [frozen-indices]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,621][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [ingest-attachment]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,622][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,623][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,623][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,623][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [kibana]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,624][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,624][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,624][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,624][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [legacy-geo]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,625][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,625][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [mapper-version]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,625][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [old-lucene-versions]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,625][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [parent-join]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,626][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [percolator]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,633][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,634][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [reindex]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,634][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [repositories-metering-api]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,634][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [repository-azure]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,634][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [repository-encrypted]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,635][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [repository-gcs]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,635][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [repository-s3]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,635][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [repository-url]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,635][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [runtime-fields-common]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,635][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [search-business-rules]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,636][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [searchable-snapshots]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,638][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [snapshot-based-recoveries]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,638][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [snapshot-repo-test-kit]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,638][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [spatial]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,638][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [systemd]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,639][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [transform]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,639][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,639][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [unsigned-long]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,639][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [vector-tile]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,639][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [wildcard]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,639][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-aggregate-metric]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,640][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-analytics]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,645][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-async]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,645][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-async-search]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-autoscaling]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-enrich]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-eql]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,646][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-fleet]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,647][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,647][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-identity-provider]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,649][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,649][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,649][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,649][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,650][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-ql]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,650][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,650][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,650][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-shutdown]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,650][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,651][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-stack]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,651][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-text-structure]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,655][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-voting-only-node]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,655][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2022-09-27T10:49:42,656][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [node-1] no plugins loaded
[2022-09-27T10:49:50,310][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node-1] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [3.1gb], net total_space [19.5gb], types [rootfs]
[2022-09-27T10:49:50,314][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [node-1] heap size [256mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2022-09-27T10:49:50,331][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [node-1] node name [node-1], node ID [WHujxIoTQVCOHA2NuQKXqg], cluster name [my-application], roles [data_frozen, ingest, data_cold, data, remote_cluster_client, master, data_warm, data_content, transform, data_hot, ml]
[2022-09-27T10:49:56,448][ERROR][o.e.b.Elasticsearch      ] [node-1] fatal exception while booting Elasticsearch
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: invalid SSL configuration for xpack.security.transport.ssl - server ssl configuration requires a key and certificate, but these have not been configured; you must set either [xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path], or both [xpack.security.transport.ssl.key] and [xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.validateServerConfiguration(SSLService.java:635) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.loadSslConfigurations(SSLService.java:612) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.ssl.SSLService.<init>(SSLService.java:156) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createSSLService(XPackPlugin.java:463) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.XPackPlugin.createComponents(XPackPlugin.java:312) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$new$15(Node.java:696) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.lambda$flatMap$0(PluginsService.java:236) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:575) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:616) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(ReferencePipeline.java:622) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(ReferencePipeline.java:627) ~[?:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:710) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:311) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch$2.<init>(Elasticsearch.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.initPhase3(Elasticsearch.java:214) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:67) ~[elasticsearch-8.4.2.jar:?]
```

Comment: I saw there is a directory `/etc/elasticsearch/certs/` and inside there are three files: `http_ca.crt`, `http.p12` and `transport.p12`. so I set `xpack.security.transport.ssl.key: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/transport.p12` and `xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/transport.p12`, and did not work: `cannot load PEM certificate_authorities from [/etc/elasticsearch/certs/transport.p12] due to CertificateParsingException (signed fields invalid)`. I also tried to set `xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate: /etc/elasticsearch/certs/http_ca.crt`, not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [setup basic security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup.html#security-basic-setup) and [secure HTTP](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup-https.html#encrypt-kibana-browser) steps and generate transport key+cert and HTTP key+cert.

Then run command `openssl x509 -req -in httpCert.csr -signkey httpCert.key -out httpCert.crt` to generate the HTTP cert file. and put them in the directory `/etc/elasticsearch/certs/` and `/etc/elasticsearch/certs/httpCert` respectively.

Then config in `/etc/elasticsearch.yml`:

```
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.type: PKCS12

xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities: certs/elastic-stack-ca.pem
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.type: PKCS12

xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.http.ssl.key: certs/httpCert/httpCert.key
xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate: certs/httpCert/httpCert.crt
```

Start/restart elasticsearch and it is up: `systemctl start elasticsearch.service`.

```
[root@ecs-140825 elasticsearch]# curl -X GET "https://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=50s&pretty" --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/httpCert/httpCert.crt  -k -u elastic
Enter host password for user 'elastic':
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 1,
  "active_shards" : 1,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 100.0
}
```

Comment: Which key `transport.ssl` or `http.ssl` is responsible for the HTTPS Server (to HTTP clients) and which is responsible for communication between the cluster nodes?

Comment: transport.ssl - communication between cluster nodes, http.ssl - HTTP clients